# How do i apply a style to multiple li elements in js?

Tags: javascript, html-lists

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelector("li");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeydown(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.key === "Enter") {
        createListElement();
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
    
input.addEventListener("keydown", addListAfterKeydown);

li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    li.classList.add("done");
} )
```

```
.coolTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  word-spacing: -8px;
  color: tomato;
  text-shadow: 
    -1px -1px 0 firebrick,
    -2px -2px 0 firebrick,
    -3px -3px 0 firebrick,
    -4px -4px 0 firebrick,
    -5px -5px 0 firebrick,
    -6px -6px 0 firebrick,
    -7px -7px 0 firebrick,
    -8px -8px 0 firebrick,
    -30px 20px 40px dimgrey;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

It first worked when i just used "querySelector"(without all) but just for the first item. What can i change to apply the style line-through for all the li items that I click on?

I also tried to use the the querySelector on ul but nothing happens.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamically added `li` item doesn't have a click event attached to it. You manually add the click event handler to each you create, but I would use event delegation. The idea is simple, you add one click event handler to the parent (`ul` in this case), and whenever the parent or it's children are click, you check if which specific child was clicked, and act if one is found.

Attach the event handler to the `ul`, when an item is clicked, get the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) `li` from `e.target`, and if the or it's parents are a `li` item, add the class to the `li` item:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeydown(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.key === "Enter") {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keydown", addListAfterKeydown);

ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var el = e.target.closest('li');
  if(el) el.classList.add("done");
})
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input id="userinput">

<button id="enter">Add</button>

<ul></ul>
```